# I refreshed the cache in my opencart website and now the website is not loading?

Tags: php, icons, opencart, opencart-3

After making Some changes in the code and refreshing using Modification i am enable to load my Website

Comment: you need to provide more details. what is the error?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Action::execute() /home/public_html/system/engine/event.php on line 62